# How to circumvent Compute Engine's downtime during container deployments?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I plan to use Compute Engine with containers, but everytime I update the container image via `gcloud compute instances update-container ...` it takes some (down)time stopping and preparing the instance, which causes downtime in the production environment of my application. What pipeline or cloud strategy would you put in place to mitigate this behaviour?

Comment: Consider adding a managed instance group (MIG) and a load balancer. During updates, the MIG can add another instance so that there is always one running instance. A single Compute Engine instance will have downtime no matter how you configure CI/CD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Updating a container on a VM instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers#updating_a_container_on_a_vm_instance) docs,

> When you update a VM running a container, Compute Engine performs two
> steps:
>
> 1. Updates container declaration on the instance. Compute Engine stores the updated container declaration in [instance metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata)
>    under the gce-container-declaration metadata key.
> 2. [Stops and restarts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stop-start-instance) the instance to actuate the updated configuration, if the instance is running. If the instance is stopped,
>    update the container declaration and keep the instance stopped. The VM
>    instance downloads the new image and launches the container on VM
>    start.

To avoid Application downtime make use of **Managed Instance Group**.
Managed instance groups maintain high availability of your applications by proactively keeping your instances available, which means in **Running** state. A MIG automatically recreates an instance that is not Running.

So, [Deploy a container on a managed instance group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers#managedinstancegroupcontainer) and [Update a MIG to a new version of a container image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers#updating_a_mig_to_a_new_version_of_a_container_image).